# Accessing a block types content programatically

Tags: theming, 8, blocks, hooks

I have created a block type in the drupal 8 UI (structure/block/block-content/types ) that has two fields that are just strings. I then created 4 pieces of content using that block_type. How do I access the content created by the block type in hook_preprocessor_html programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

This is a cutdown version of the function to access the block entities.

```
function _access_content_block_fields_build_arr($bidArr, $fieldRequestArr)
{

    $return = array();
    $blockElements = array();
    $blocks = \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::loadMultiple($bidArr);
    foreach ($blocks as $block) {
        foreach ($fieldRequestArr as $fieldRequest) {
            $blockResult = $block->get($fieldRequest)->getValue();
            $blockElements[$fieldRequest] = $blockResult[0]; 
        }
        $return[] = $blockElements;
    }

    return $return;
}
```

purencool.com/accessing-a-block-types-content-programatically is the entire function for image fields url as well